# TinyMCE theme files missing when used with LaravelMix

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, webpack, tinymce

I tried to use TinyMCE with plain HTML & jquery, like below and it works fine.

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#comment'
    });
</script>
```

But when I try to do same with latest Laravel mix, referring TinyMCE from node_modules, it gives me errors like `GET http://localhost:3000/js/themes/modern/theme.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Somebody please tell me what will be a good place include/require TinyMCE library and how to refer that.

I tried referring it like below in app.js

```
require('tinymce/tinymce.min.js');
```

and

```
require('tinymce');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out after some trouble: Need to import individual plugins which are being used in initialization.

**Worked in my case. Improvements are welcome.**

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Import TinyMCE and required theme/plugins

```
import tinymce from 'tinymce/tinymce';
import 'tinymce/themes/modern/theme';
import 'tinymce/plugins/colorpicker';
import 'tinymce/plugins/link';
import 'tinymce/plugins/lists';
import 'tinymce/plugins/anchor';
import 'tinymce/plugins/advlist';
import 'tinymce/plugins/table';
import 'tinymce/plugins/textcolor';
import 'tinymce/plugins/paste';
import 'tinymce/plugins/help';
import 'tinymce/plugins/charmap';
import 'tinymce/plugins/contextmenu';
```

HTML

`<textarea name="description" class="form-control" id="description" rows="3"></textarea>`

Initialize

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#description',
    skin: false,
    plugins: [
        'advlist lists link charmap anchor textcolor',
        'table contextmenu paste help'
    ],
    toolbar: 'insert | undo redo |  formatselect | bold italic backcolor  | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help',
});
```

Run Laravel dev server

```
npm run development -- --watch
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the cleanest solution as of 2020.

Install tinymce via NPM:

```
npm i tinymce
```

Add these requires to `resources/js/app.js`:

```
require('tinymce');
require('tinymce/themes/silver');
```

Add this line to `webpack.mix.js`:

```
mix.copy('node_modules/tinymce/skins', 'public/js/skins');
```

Then do `npm run dev` and you're good to go.

Comment: That did the trick, but you also need to add any plugins you're using under ```app.js```. For example: ```require('tinymce/plugins/autolink');``` 
```require('tinymce/plugins/advlist');```

Answer (score 1):

I followed the solutions I found on this page but in both cases, something was missing.

This is what worked for me.

Add to resources/js/app.js:

```
require('tinymce');
require('tinymce/themes/silver');

require('tinymce/icons/default');

require('tinymce/plugins/advlist');
require('tinymce/plugins/autolink');
require('tinymce/plugins/link');
require('tinymce/plugins/image');
require('tinymce/plugins/lists');
require('tinymce/plugins/charmap');
require('tinymce/plugins/charmap');
require('tinymce/plugins/print');
require('tinymce/plugins/preview');
require('tinymce/plugins/spellchecker');
require('tinymce/plugins/media');
require('tinymce/plugins/table');

require('./tinymce-configuration');
```

Create a file resources/js/tinymce-configuration.js:

```
var editor_config = {
    selector: '.textarea_tinymce',

    // Remove Html tags from paste text
    paste_as_text: true, //!important

    // Allow link target blank
    extended_valid_elements: 'a[href|target]',

    plugins : 'advlist autolink link image lists charmap print preview spellchecker media table',

    theme: 'silver',
    height: 400,

    toolbar: 'bold | bullist  link ', 
    blockquote | link image media  | hr',

    menubar: false,
    path_absolute : "/",
    relative_urls: false,
}
```

Add this line to webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.copy('node_modules/tinymce/skins', 'public/js/skins');
```

Run:

```
npm run dev
```